# Is there a way to return a class instance from redux - specifically redux tool kit?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My goal is receive a class instance from useAppSelector vs a plain object.

This returns a plain object

```
const {item} = useAppSelector((state) => state)
```

This works but it is not clean and adds a lot of code duplication.

```
const {item} = useAppSelector((state) => state)
const classItem = new Item(item)
```

What are your ideas for the best achieve this?

Comment: Better approach: memoize the class instances and keep them cached somewhere, use the data from `item` as a key to access the cache. Classes encapsulate behavior (methods) which is not serializable, global application state.

Answer (score 0):

**No - please *don't* do this!**  Redux (and React) expect that your app uses plain JS objects and arrays, with immutable updates - *not* class instances:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions
- https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state